# Move content next to sidebar generated by JS to the right

Tags: css

I made a game with JavaScript and a sidebar for the page which I'm happy with, but I'm not sure how to make the game (loaded with JavaScript) move to the right of the sidebar. Can this be accomplished using CSS?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ececec;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.info-panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Allows game to display next to panel rather than below it */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-panel">
  <h2>Arcade Game</h2>
  <p>Use the arrow keys to get to the water.</p>
  <h4>Score: <span id="score"></span></h4>
</div>
```

[image]

Edit: I just added a class to the canvas element creating the game board in the JS and added a left margin for it in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
CSS:

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ececec;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.info-panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Allows game to display next to panel rather than below it */
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
 <div class="info-panel">
    <h2>Arcade Game</h2>
    <p>Use the arrow keys to get to the water.</p>
    <h4>Score: <span id="score"></span></h4>
  </div>

  <script src="js/resources.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/engine.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sidebar might overlap on the game, you might need to give `margin-right` to the game area as well.